# pandas calulate difference based on a pattern

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as

```
 df
  Category NET    A    B  C_DIFF    1    2  DD_DIFF .....
0      tom  CD   10   20     NaN   30   40     NaN
1      tom  CD  100  200     NaN  300  400     NaN
2      tom  CD  100  200     NaN  300  400     NaN
3      tom  CD  100  200     NaN  300  400     NaN
4      tom  CD  100  200     NaN  300  400     NaN
```

Now my columns name ending with _DIFF i.e,C_DIFF and DD_DIFF should get the subsequent difference. i.e, A-B values should be in C_DIFF and 1-2 difference should be populated DD_DIFF. How to get this desired output.

Edit : There are 20 columns ending with _DIFF. Need to do this programmatically and not hard code the columns

Comment: How can the programatic way know which columns are to be used for which DIFF ending column? Can we rely on the order of columns starting with the 3rd?

Comment: Yes. We can rely on the order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generalizing this:

```
m=df.columns.get_indexer(df.filter(like='DIFF').columns)
df.iloc[:,m]=pd.concat([df.iloc[:,a]-df.iloc[:,b] for a,b in zip(m-2,m-1)],axis=1).values
print(df)
```

---

```
  Category NET    A    B  C_DIFF    1    2  DD_DIFF
0      tom  CD   10   20     -10   30   40      -10
1      tom  CD  100  200    -100  300  400     -100
2      tom  CD  100  200    -100  300  400     -100
3      tom  CD  100  200    -100  300  400     -100
4      tom  CD  100  200    -100  300  400     -100
```

***Explanation:***

[`df.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) will filter the columns with names `DIFF`.

`df.columns.get_indexer` is using [`pd.Index.get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) which gets the index of such columns.

Post this we zip them and calculate the difference, and store in a list and concat them. Finally access the values to assign.

***EDIT***:
To handle strings you can take help of [`pd.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`:

```
m=df.columns.get_indexer(df.filter(like='DIFF').columns)
df.iloc[:,m]=pd.concat([pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,a],errors='coerce')-
 pd.to_numeric(df.iloc[:,b],errors='coerce') for a,b in zip(m-2,m-1)],axis=1).values
```

Comment: Nice. But how to handle exceptions.i.e, if one of the value is a string and we try to subtract it....How to handle the exception in this case